# Optimal endianness conversions and signed integers

Tags: c, type-conversion, endianness

I am looking for the fastest way to read numerical values stored in binary files.

I have done some functions that seem to work, but I'd like to get a feedback on whether or not my implementation is good.

Here is how I get a signed integer from a 4-bytes little endian block:

```
signed long int from4li(char const * const buffer)
{
    signed long int value = 0;

    value += (unsigned char) buffer[3];
    value <<= 8;
    value += (unsigned char) buffer[2];
    value <<= 8;
    value += (unsigned char) buffer[1];
    value <<= 8;
    value += (unsigned char) buffer[0];

    return value;
}
```

This would also work for unsigned integers, but I've originally made a different implementation for unsigned integers (that fails with signed integers, I don't know exactly why):

```
unsigned long int fromu4li(char const * const buffer)
{
    unsigned long int value = 0;

    value += (unsigned char) buffer[0] << 8 * 0;
    value += (unsigned char) buffer[1] << 8 * 1;
    value += (unsigned char) buffer[2] << 8 * 2;
    value += (unsigned char) buffer[3] << 8 * 3;

    return value;
}
```

I am more sure about the conversion from an integer to a little endian string buffer, which I think probably couldn't be optimized further:

```
void to4li(long int const value, char * const buffer)
{
    buffer[0] = value >> 8 * 0;
    buffer[1] = value >> 8 * 1;
    buffer[2] = value >> 8 * 2;
    buffer[3] = value >> 8 * 3;
}
```

I also think that it could be even faster usign memcpy, but to use memcpy I have to know the endianness of the host system.

I don't really want to rely on the endianness of the host system, as I think that my code should be independent of the internal data representation of the host system.

So, is this a proper way of doing those conversions, or can I improve my functions?

Comment: Why not just `uint32_t integer = (c0 << 0) | (c1 << 8) | (c2 << 16) | (c3 << 24)` and `uint8_t *buf = (uint8_t *)&number; c0 = buf[0]; c1 = buf[1];` etc.

Comment: `uint32_t integer = (c0 << 0) | (c1 << 8) | (c2 << 16) | (c3 << 24)` seems like a nice way. But how is it going to work with signed numbers?

Comment: @alartur, after `uint32_t integer = (c0 << 0) | (c1 << 8) | (c2 << 16) | (c3 << 24);`, then `int32_t signed_integer = (int32_t)(integer);` will make it become signed numbers.

Comment: Looks like `c0`, `c1`, … need to be of type `unsigned char` so it can work (see example in answer). Why?

Comment: @alartur: Pretty sure it's implementation-defined whether a `char` is signed or unsigned.  If you want one or the other, and care about your code being portable, you have to specify which one you want.  Otherwise, if it's signed, it will be sign-extended in order to turn it into an `int` to work with the `<<` operator.  As a char, -1 turns into 0xff...but as an int, -1 turns into 0xffffffff.  And that's assuming your numbers are two's complement, which (although it's by far the most common representation of integer types) isn't assumed by the standard either, and portable code can't assume it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier way, and one that avoids undefined behaviour due to bit-shifting a signed integral variable, is to just copy the data bitwise:

```
int32_t get(char const * const buf)
{
    int32_t result;
    char * const p = reinterpret_cast<char *>(&result);
    std::copy(buf, buf + sizeof result, p);
    return result;
}
```

This code assumes that the data has the *same* endianness as the machien. Alternatively, you can use `std::copy_backward` to *reverse* the endianness.

This method depends both on the stream data and the host machine endianness, and thus it isn't as elegant as the algebraic solution for unsigned integers, which *only* depends on the stream data. However, since signed integers are platform dependent anyway, this is supposedly an acceptable compromise.

(Just for comparison, for unsigned integers I'd prefer this machine-independent code:

```
template <typename UInt>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<UInt>::value, UInt>::type
get_from_le(unsigned char * const buf)
{
    UInt result;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(UInt); ++i)
        result += (buf[i] << (8 * i));
    return result;
}
```

Usage: `auto ui = get_from_le<uint64_t>(buf);`.

For the big-endian version, replace `[i]` by `[sizeof(UInt) - i - 1]`.)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the long answer. Unfortunately I am not going to use this as I am writing in C, but will learn how it works.

Comment: @alartur: You can do the same in C. The cast is just a normal cast; for `std::copy` you can use `memcpy`, and the template is just a concise way to express the code for all integral types at once -- in C you have to spell out each one separately (or make a macro).

Answer (score 0):

Using bitwise OR seems to be a good idea, but there is something strange:

After testing, it seems like `c0`, `c1`, `c2`, `c3` need to be unsigned chars in order this solution to work. Again, I don't know why:

Take, for example, 0x8080, which is -3264 (signed) or 32896 (unsigned).

Using

```
char c0 = 0x80;
char c1 = 0x80;
```

I get:

```
uint16_t res = (c0 << 0) | (c1 << 8);
// res = 65408 ???
```

But

```
uint16_t res = ((unsigned char) c0 << 0) | ((unsigned char) c1 << 8);
// res = 32896 ok
```

Comment: It is called Type Cast, char c0 is equal to -128 which binary form is 10000000, first cast from char to int, its binary form is 1111111110000000, and second cast from int to uint, its binary form is explaned by computer as 65408(dec), same with char c1, the result of (`(c1 <<    0 | (c2 << 8))` is 65408(dec), binary form is 1111111110000000. And if you first cast c0 or c1 to unsigned char, the cast is different, the first cast is from unsigned char to unsigned int, binary form is same but explaned by value is different, it becomes 128(dec).So the anwser is different between them.

Comment: My English is poor, hope you will understand my explanation